# MVC 3 HTML 5 and HTML 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

I have a MVC 3 project and I enable the HTML 5 markup. For the HTML 5 part, it is running fine.

Now I created a partial view and copy and paste some code into it

The first line is

```
<div id="Header">
```

I want to use this partial view in my view which is html 4 markup.

The problem comes, the razor engine automatically convert my

```
<div id="Header">
```

into

```
<Header>
```

I don't want to use HTML 5 for this view but only HTML 4. What should I do?

Comment: Not entirely on topic, but can you elaborate on the reason why the partial view can't be html5 as well?

Comment: hi, my project has two parts. One is for admin, one is for the front-end. I have two different website templates. The HTML 5 template is for the admin, and for the front part, I am using a HTML 4 template. The partial view I am talking about is for the front part which should be HTML 4.

Comment: What happens if you change the div id to something other than header?

Comment: You need to provide more details, preferably a small, working example for this. I tried to reproduce this by (1) creating a new MVC3 app with html5 markup, then (2) adding a partial view with the mentioned div and (3) added the partial view to the `_Layout.cshtml` file: it was just rendered as `<div id="Header">`.

Comment: Also not exactly your question, but what about using modernizr. It is meant to provide backward support for html5 semantic markup.

Comment: I'm completely baffled by this question. Does that really happen in MVC3? A `<div id="header>` automatically replaced by `<header>`? Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the div as follows, it won't get swapped out:

```
<div id="strap">
```

Which may solve your immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to covert back to:

```
<div id="Header">
```

where  is the way to go in the future?

If you worried about the compatibility with the older browser, you can simply implement modernizr-2.6.2.js. (which should come with the Visual Studio web projects)

This will make all the basic HTML5 works in older browser.
(tho haven't tested with browser older than IE6)

Answer (score 0):

you could always use a class instead of an id

```
<div class="header">
```

this has the added advantage of not making your css (if any) for this element very specific, and also means that the ID cannot be reused.

you can still select your element using jQuery selector using it's class as the selector

```
$('.header')
```

Answer (score 0):

question for you: Did you created the Html 4 partial view  in Html 5 view? ; If your answer is yes, the problem you mentioned is occurring naturally. When MVC renders your page, he first renders the Html 5 part(the layout master page). As a result, Html5  type doc type will be chosen by default. After that when the Html 4 partial view is rendered, the engine renders it under a mark up support for Html 5.

if i want to summarize what i wanted to say:

```
<html>
      //Html 4 partial view.
</html>
```

This will make a Html 5 markup view no matter what Html4 code you wrote in that partial view. If i am wrong, let me know. I will learn from my mistakes. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use Transitional doctype on the top of your partial view page. Because HTML engine understand the page according to doctype.